# Microsoft azure mobile service does not show the tables existing already in the database

Tags: php, android, sql, azure

_I'm making an android app with Microsoft azure mobile service and it does not show the tables existing already in the database it's only showing tables that have been created in the mobile service
how should I use the data existing in the Database .

### if there is no solution

_I have seen a PHP connection String in the sql database , if i used a PHP scripts what should be the URL to use in the android application 
Help in one of them please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have figured it out !
it was the schema name
if you create a mobile service the tables of this in the database will have your service name as a schema
changing the schema name will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, your problem is the following: You created a table in the database (e.g. using the SQL Server Management Platform or a Visual Studio connection) and the table is then not showing up in the Management Portal of the Mobile Service.

**Solution**

If so, you can make them show up by creating a "new" database table with the **same table name** that already exists in the database. In fact the table is not created again but it shows up in the Management Portal with the same structure and data as it is in the database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem, i see the mobile service in visual studio but there is no table under the node. In the tutorial, it says to right click the table to edit the permissions but there is no table.  Is there a way to edit the table permission some other way?

Comment: As far as I know you can only change permissions via the management portal. So go to your mobile service at managewindowsazure.com and click "Data". There, select the table and click on "permissions" afterwards. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I dont see the Data option in management portal. I click on the mobile service and get the (Dashboard, Scheduler, Push Identity Configure, Scale, Logs) menu.

Comment: What backend type did you choose? If you chose .NET backend, then you can change the permissions by adding an `[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]` attribute in your Table Controller class (or methods in this class)

Comment: Thanks, i will try this attribute. I choose the .net backend.